# is GLM the best way to deal with a (numeric IV+ categorical IV =binary DV) dataset? how to plot?

Tags: glm

i have a dataset includes 1 numeric IV + 5 categorical IVs , the DV is also binary, so i used glmer to explore the predication effects:

```
$model <- glmer(Y~(Xn+Xc1+Xc2+Xc3+Xc3)^2+(1|id),data,family=binomial)
```

but is this the best way? and how to plot the main effect and interactions?

Comment: What programming language is this - R?

Comment: Another hint: If your question is more statistics related (rather than programming) there is also https://stats.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @stats007 thanks for the reply! it's r and i think it's more statistics related. so thanks for the suggestion!